# Появляется ошибка при запуске сайта на php на локальном сервере в apache

Tags: php, apache

Появляется такая ошибка  при запуске сайта на локальном сервере. что это и как решить? что то в интернете не могу найти. Fatal error: Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.3.0". You are running 7.1.33. in C:\OpenServer\domains\mysite\vendor\composer\platform_check.php on line 24

я так понял надо обновить PHP?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что не так?

Comment: да, нужно более свежий пхп. ну или отказаться от зависимостей, которые хотят его.

Comment: что за зависимости? php я так понял надо на компе обновить?

Comment: если есть композер, то значит есть зависимости. Да, пхп на компе (там где собственно запускаете)

Comment: что то я нигде не могу найти этот php. похоже как я понял надо его обновить через сервер apache

Comment: В настройках OpenServer просто смените версию PHP

Comment: Настройки -> Модули -> PHP

Comment: смена версии в OpenServer не помогло. сервер теперь вообще не загружается

Comment: На скриншоте же видно что выбран апач2.4 пхп 7.0-7.1 надо выбрать апач2.4 пхп 7.2-7.4 + PHP 7.4